# Using FireFox containers with multiple socks5 proxies with usernames and passwords

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-extensions, socks5

Using FireFox containers with multiple socks5 proxies with usernames and passwords

I'm setting up Firefox containers which I want to use **multiple different socks5 proxies** for different web sites.

[image: img1]

**How would I put in a username and password in the field below**? (where the red arrow is pointing to)

[image: img2]

Comment: look here https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html but it goes like this `type://user:password@host:port/path`

Comment: @lnee  That doesn't seem to work.  I type in `socks5://user:password@host:port` and it says "please type in valid proxy url"

Answer (score 1):

Try this: socks://user:password@host:port

Comment: Way more detail is required.

Answer (score 0):

**Looks Like mozilla just refuses to push the fix out for some reason**....They keep saying next release this issue has existed in one form or another in other reports for almost a year.

https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues/2402#issuecomment-1250122918

**UPDATE:**

"
It'll be in the next release that should be out soon

It isn't. I'm on 104.0.2 from September 6th and on beta 105.0b9. Both still have limited input to 50 characters (at least on macOS). Is there a conifg file I can put the proxy manually igoring the extension input form until it's fixed?
"